# What does "for when Albion's need is greatest" mean in the ending of the Merlin series?

Tags: merlin-bbc

Kilgharrah said to Merlin at the end of "Merlin" series.

> Arthur is not just a king. He is the Once and Future King. Take heart, for when Albion's need is greatest: Arthur will rise again.

What does Kilgharrah mean?

Comment: When wolves are 2-0 up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Albion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albion) is the oldest known name of Great Britain, the location where [Camelot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelot) is said to have been located.  [King Arthur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur) being the Once and Future King is a common part of the preexisting mythology<sup>1</sup>.

So, when Great Britain most needs him, King Arthur will return.  That is why, in the very last scene,

> Merlin is still waiting around in the modern day, near the area where Arthur died.

<sup>1</sup>That phrasing made popular by T. H. White's novel [The Once and Future King](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Once_And_Future_King), while originally:

> ... according to Le Morte d'Arthur, was said by "many men" to be written upon King Arthur's tomb: the internally rhymed hexameter Hic iacet Arthurus, rex quondam, rexque futurus — "Here lies Arthur, king once, and king to be".

Comment: Nice quote from the novel! I wonder why Merlin stayed there though... Why not return to Camelot?